# Changing default HTML Tags in Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, html, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just wanted to ask, if there is any way, to edit the default tags which come with Sublime Text 3.

For example: When I type `<style` and hit enter, Sublime just outputs me `<style type="text/css"></style>`, but what I want is just `<style></style>`, without the `type="text/css"`, because I want to have it slimmer, as the `type` attribute is not needed anymore in HTML5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could fork the package (https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/HTML/html_completions.py#L291) change the line i linked and then use that package over the default one. I don't use Sublime enough to know if it's easier than this

Comment: Thanks @DanGamble, but as we are gonna use it in production I would like to avoid to do that everywhere manually so maybe someone got a easier/faster solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a snippet (Tools > New Snippet...)

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<style>$1</style>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>sty</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Then save it as style.sublime-snippet in your `/Packages/User` folder.

It can then be called by typing `sty` + `Tab`.

Note: the `<scope>` element restricts it to only get executed on html files (or files where the syntax is set to html)

Comment: Thanks, that's another option, which works as it should and is easily to implement